# Need to merge Column Data of Excel file while exporting from vb.net App

Tags: excel, vb.net, export-to-excel

I've worksheet which is having data which is exported by WinForms Application.Please check screen shot in order to get the better idea that how the data is present in sheet [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S72hC.png). Now what i want is to merge the cells that are having the common value for Ex. one of my column is having InvoiceID so there will be some no of items inside that InvoicID. I want to merge that no of rows equal to items to that it can display only once for those records. For better understanding check this screen shot which i performed manually [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS0pT.png).
Is there any way I can perform the same using the code.
Following is the code which i use to export the data to Excel.

`Dim excelConverter As New GridGroupingExcelConverterControl

Dim exportingOptions As New ExcelExportingOptions excelConverter.ExportToExcel(GridGroupingControl1, "Sample.xlsx", exportingOptions)

Process.Start("Sample.xlsx")

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    For i = 0 To dgvSearch.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dgvSearch.ColumnCount - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                dgvSearch(j, i).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    MsgBox("You can find the file C:\vbexcel.xlsx")`
```

I am new to exporting data to excel so that will be very helpful.
Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop through. So itterate through each cell. I began writting it out, but ended up having to code it. Explaining the workings is a lot harder than just writing them :)

Heres the code, you'll need to add this into yours AFTER your For-Loop and before your SaveAs. I was a little baffled at the +1 and -2 for the i (x axis) I havent altered any of your code, i didnt want to disturb it if thats all correct.

Hope this helps

```
    For i = 1 To dgvSearch.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dgvSearch.ColumnCount - 1
            'I dont understand why +1 etc? But we need to check the current cell against the one above, to see if they are the same
            Dim cellAbove As String = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j)
            Dim cellActive As String = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
            Dim cellBelow As String = xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 2)

            If cellActive = cellAbove Then
                If cellBelow = cellActive Then
                    'There could be more below, so we leave for the moment..
                Else
                    'The cell above (and possibly more above that) are the same
                    'So we need to start itterating through the cells above to remove any duplicates
                    For y = j + 2 To 2 Step -1
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, y) = ""
                        'As we step up the column, we check the one above and two above - so we remove this one,
                        'if they both are the same, we carry on, if not - it means the one above is different
                        'to two above (hence the one above must be the one we need to keep.. :S - bear with me :)
                        If xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, y - 1) = cellActive And xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, y - 2) = cellActive Then
                        Else
                            'If they dont match, we exit - you can add a If NOT xlworksheet.... if you wanted, or keep the else here.
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Else
                'Its not the same as above, so we need to keep this cell!
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks rich, will try that.